Unable to send SMS with code, SwiftUI, FireBase Authentication, ERROR 17999 and ERROR 17010
I am developing an app on IOS 17+, my firebase-ios-sdk 10.18.0, Xcode 15.4. I need to implement login and registration in the app using phone number. But due to several kinds of errors I am not able to send sms.
The first error is

Error during phone number verification: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information. Firebase Error Code: FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: 17999)

it appears most often and is accompanied by the error

https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode, Response code: 503

as well as less frequently appears the error

Error during phone number verification: We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later. Firebase Error Code: FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: 17010)

and is accompanied by the error

https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode, Response code: 400

I have tried many solutions and here is what I can say

I have of course enabled registration with phone number in FireBase and Google Cloud Platform

Registration and Authentication works correctly if you add a test phone number

The error is not related to reCaptcha, as it passes successfully and I have rechecked the URL schemes

In Google Cloud Platform I have enabled "Cloud Identity" and "Identity Toolkit API"

The error also has nothing to do with APNs Authentication Key, because I can send notifications via Cloud Messaging without any problems.

I have also linked my credit card.


Here is my code for AppDelegate and functions related to sending a message
    func startAuth(phoneNumber: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        print("Starting phone number verification for: \(phoneNumber)")
        
        // Установить isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting в true для тестирования
       // Auth.auth().settings?.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = true
        
        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { verificationID, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error during phone number verification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode.Code(rawValue: (error as NSError).code) {
                    print("Firebase Error Code: \(errorCode)")
                }
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
            completion(true)
        }
    }

    func verifyCode(smsCode: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        guard let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID") else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: smsCode)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error verifying code: \(error)")
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            completion(true)
        }
    }
    
    func resendCode(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
            guard let phoneNumber = tempUserData?["phoneNumber"] as? String else {
                completion(false)
                return
            }

            startAuth(phoneNumber: phoneNumber) { success in
                completion(success)
            }
        }

    func registerUser(userData: [String: Any], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        db.collection("users").document(uid).setData(userData) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error registering user: \(error)")
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            completion(true)
        }
    }

and
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
//        let providerFactory = AppCheckDebugProviderFactory()
//        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
                let providerFactory = YourAppCheckProviderFactory()
                AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        print("App Check provider factory set")

        // Запрос разрешения на отправку уведомлений
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        print("Remote notifications registered")

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Обработка регистрации удаленных уведомлений
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
        print("Remote notifications token registered")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        // Обработка ошибки регистрации удаленных уведомлений
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // Обработка полученных уведомлений
        if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
        // This notification is not handled by Firebase Authentication.
        // Handle the notification yourself, as appropriate.
    }
}

class YourAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
  func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
      return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
    } else {
      return DeviceCheckProvider(app: app)
    }
  }


Be aware there is a usage quota per plan for Phone Auth in Firebase. (e.g. 10 SMS/day in a free plan)
As for the error of FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: 17999), it might exactly be caused by the limitation. It works with a test phone number since the restriction doesn't apply to the test phone numbers.
Regarding the error of FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: 17010), it is most probably because there's another limitation you can't send an SMS to the same phone number in a short period.
Those are all written in the document, so I recommend you look over it again.
